# Foreach with 2D (Multi-Dimensional) input names, how to grab the data & update database?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have looked everywhere so I apologize if there's an answer to this already, I couldn't find it after hours of searching. Maybe it's not a good way to do it either...

I have a form that has "picks" of a litter, so 1st pick, 2nd pick, 3rd pick, etc. These picks also have genders (Female, Male)

I use a foreach query to grab the available pick spots. If someone isn't assigned to that pick spot, then the input field is enabled for manual typing

Within that foreach query, I need to somehow submit what pick it is and what gender, as well as the typed value, so I can find the pick and store it to the database... The other problem is, it's dynamic where someone may type in 3 input fields, or other times just 1 input field. Basically it'll show 3 input fields and the user can choose to use all 3 or just 1...

No matter what I've tried, it doesn't work. I don't even have my examples because I've tried everything I could find and had to scrap it all

The input, this is for males only but females are the same:

```
<?php 
foreach ($malespickedquery as $pick){
$picktaken=$pick['user_id'];
$pickcustom=$pick['custom_name']; 
$pickposition=$pick['pick_id'];
$suffix=ordinal($pickposition);
?>
<div class="form-row pb-3">
    <div class="col-12">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $pickposition.$suffix." Pick "; ?>Male:</label>
    <?php if($pickcustom==true){ ?>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $pickcustom; ?>" />
    <?php }elseif($picktaken!="0"){ ?>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $pick['public_name']; ?>" disabled />
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <input type="text" name="malepicks[<?php echo $pickposition; ?>][male][]" class="form-control" value="" />
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I've tried foreach within foreach, but can never get all information. Most things just return the last input field as well... So if 3 of them are generated, the last input field would come through but not the others. I also did something with foreach where it returned ALL of the fields, even blank ones, which just got confusing and still didn't work right

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The good news is that you aren't creating bad html by duplicating `id` attributes for elements in your repeatable fields -- you  are already doing better than 90% of the askers on SO.  You also know how to use array syntax with your `name` attributes.  I believe you should just use `foreach($malespickedquery as $i => $pick) {` then use that `$i` as your first level key for your repeatable fields.  Yes?  Or is `malepicks[<?php echo $pickposition; ?>][male]` enough?  Maybe I'm not following the context / business logic. The empty `name` attributes look troublesome.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks!! I'm not familiar with the whole $i thing, it gets confusing whenever I try to use it haha. Maybe I'll read more into that! The thing is, the $pickposition is pulled from the database to determine which one is available.. lol. As for the empty name inputs, those are disabled and mainly used for echoing out a name that is in that spot (if one exists haha) - I did just notice the $pickcustom input field isn't disabled but that'll be to allow them to edit the custom name, if I ever get that far I'll set the name lol. It's a very confusing setup :(

Comment: @mickmackusa It's a deposit management page. So the site user inputs information about a client and gives them a pick spot... So for instance, if someone makes a deposit on a puppy, the site user will then type in "John Doe" in my foreach input fields, then submit that to assign the spot to John Doe. I have other queries that automatically assign client IDs to those picks, but that's not what this form is for lol

Comment: I'm going to walk away from this question, but I just want to say that no matter what logic you bake into this client-facing form, you will NEED to re-enforce the logic on the server-side (the submission receiving script) because it is VERY easy for someone to modify your html form in their browser, and reserve a puppy that is already claimed.  You must fiercely protect your application and assume the worst of humanity (and bots).

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm not concerned, nobody else can access it except for a site user who has permission... All my queries and forms are under permission walls lol. So the form wouldn't even render unless they had permission... Even if they could get it to render, the queries check user IDs, permissions, and even specific litter IDs for those picks before it'll let it submit... Thanks tho!